# Intellij (Android Studio) git integration: Where is .git?

Tags: android, git, version-control, intellij-idea, android-studio

I cloned my Android application project from a remote git repository. I'm developing this project in Android Studio. Have been managing version control on command line, and now trying to enable git integration on the IDEA interface. For this I clicked "Integrate Project" in VCS menu. But it seems to have ignored the .git directory and created a new one somewhere else (where?).

How do I "point" Android studio to the .git which is located in the root directory of my project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to click `Android Studio > Preferences`

[image: pref]

Under the `Version Control` tab there are many settings, including the `add` button.

[image: vcs screen]

You should get to this screen, where you can add your `.git` file.

[image: git add]

Comment: I tried that, but when I browse the root directory of my project, I can't see the .git directory.

Comment: Did you clone the project through the IDE? I would recommend just committing and pushing all local changes via command line, then cloning it through the Android Studio welcome page.

Comment: Really master class